# Computed font size is bigger than defined in CSS on the Asus Nexus 7

Tags: html, css

I run the web page on Asus Nexus 7 (written in jQueryMobile).
I have set font size in CSS for 14px but during debugging (using Chrome on the PC) I can see that its computed size is 22px.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
    <div id="summaryContent">
        <div class="contentPanel">
            <div class="header">
                Some nice info with 14px
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="headerText">
                    Text with size of 22px (but should be 14px)
                </div>
                <div class="element">
                    Text with size of 22px (but should be 14px)
                    <span class="dateInfo"> 30.11.2012</span>
                </div>
                <div class="element">
                    Text with size of 22px (but should be 14px)
                    <span class="dateInfo"> 2012</span>
                </div>
                <div class="element">
                    Text with size of 22px (but should be 14px)
                    <span class="dateInfo"> 1981</span>
                </div>
                <div class="headerText">
                    Text with size of 22px (but should be 14px)
                </div>
                <div class="element">
                    Text with size of 22px (but should be 14px)
                </div>
                <div class="element">
                    Text with size of 22px (but should be 14px)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `class="header"` div is 14px, but the next ones are 22px.

CSS code:

```
.contentPanel > div
{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}


.contentPanel div.header,
{
    font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contentPanel div.content
{
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B5B5B5;
}

.contentPanel div.content div.element {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.contentPanel div.content span.dateInfo {
    color: #7a7a7a;
}

.headerText {
    color: #454545;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I checked that Text Scaling is 100%. Is it bug on Asus Nexus 7? Is it possible to make it 14px? On iPad and on Samsung Galaxy Tab everything is ok.

#### Update 20.11.2012:

I made suggested changes but they didn't help. 
Code in JavaScript works like this:

- I create HTML in JS
- Then I insert this newly created HTML into DOM
- At this point (before changing page) in Chrome debugger (that is connected to Nexus) I can see 14px.
- Then jQueryMobile changePage() is called and then font size changes.

#### Update 20.11.2012 #2

jQueryMobile applies class ui-page-active to the part of DOM tree that is supposed to be shown on the screen.

CSS:

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page-active { display: block; overflow: visible; }
```

Before applying this class the font size is 14px, but after it, it increases to 18px or 22px. Sometimes it works ok. I checked that on iPad and on Samsung Galaxy Tab and it works fine.

Sometimes entering page again revert font size to 14px, similar thing happens while rotating device.

Comment: Please also post ALL your css.

Comment: You might want to show the complete HTML, particularly the viewport setting used in the head, or create a jsfiddle.net example that shows the issue.

Answer (score 26):

This might be something to do with [Font Boosting](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=FontBoosting).

To disable for a particular element, provide `max-height: 1000000px` on the element, parent or grandfather element.

Alternatively, provide

```
body, body * {
    max-height: 1000000px;
}
```

to disable Font Boosting on an entire page.

Comment: haha wow, how did you figure this out? Seems so far fetched.. So the font boosting algorithm takes the max-height of the parent element into account.. is this a safe way of disabling font-boosting?

Comment: My Google Fu found the linked bug report, in which they state the work around.  This solution is a bit of a blanket solution. In the linked bug report, they say that 'any fixed height greater than the actual height will do' and 'setting it on the parent or grandparent block (but not higher up than that) will usually also work'. Setting to such a large number means that even of the font size changes, the font boosting will still be disabled.

Comment: Thank you @Reuben! I have spent a day to chase this bug until I found your response.

Comment: it has to do with font boosting but setting the viewport (as suggested by Siobhan) is cleaner

Answer (score 5):

I posted a potential answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261446/1156119).

Your problem is likely due to Chrome's text scaling setting, which sets text at a particular scale for accessibility reasons. A lot of users use this who struggle to read small text on their mobile. You cannot fix this and shouldn't try to resolve it, especially with sites that support mobile devices.

[image: Chrome accessibility options]

I recommend you either ignore it or modify your CSS so that it supports slightly differing text sizes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a problem with font boosting, you may want to check that the viewport is set in your metadata:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

Is very difficult to answer without having the CSS code.

Please review from where is taken the attribute, maybe is inherited from a parent element. You can do that using firebug or the console in Google Chrome (Press F12) and browse the div.

Also you can "force" the use of an attribute using !important in your css rule:

```
.fontsize14px {
   font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

Also review that you wrote correctly the property or the class name. Sometimes is only a typo the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution did not help.

Comment: @rdkit Why? What did you find in Firebug? I see the inheritance is not direct. Try using .content > div instead. Look this link: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Comment: Did not help, please look at updates I inserted to the question.

Answer (score 1):

!important flag did not help in my case (Firefox on Windows desktop). My case was due to quirks mode.

Solution is to either use the standard mode, or override the font inheritance in the quirks mode ([Fixing table inheritance in Quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Fixing_Table_Inheritance_in_Quirks_Mode))

1. Turn standards mode by adding the doctype declaration

   `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`
2. or apply the workaround in quirks mode:

   ```
   table, caption { font-size: inherit; }
   ```

   The same is applicable to other font attributes:

   ```
   font-weight: inherit;
   font-style: inherit;
   font-variant: inherit;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I hope it helps someone. Unfortunately, I do not have access to this tablet any more and to the project where that problem occurred so I am not able to test that solution.

Comment: If this was happening only on tablet then i believe this does not address your specific issue. I had the problem on desktop FF and none of the answers solved my issue.

Comment: If you are targeting desktop browsers to honor exact settings, this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has `Minimum font size` setting, which will override your `CSS` style. If you have this style:

```
.tiny-tiny-text { font-size: 1px; }
```

But the setting is set to 7 px, your font size will never be smaller then 7 px.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mobile browser may sometimes **increase font-size on some elements** for **readability**, it's an old feature. Disabling `text-size-adjust` did the job for me:

```
html {
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

See more : https://kilianvalkhof.com/2022/css-html/your-css-reset-needs-text-size-adjust-probably/