# Calculated font-size on Nexus 7 Chrome is different from CSS font-size

Tags: android, css, responsive-design, cross-browser, font-size

I have some CSS and HTML where the `font-size` is explicitly styled to be 13px, and for the most part it stays that way, but occasionally Chrome on the Nexus 7 sometimes displays a part of the same page as 14px;

Unfortunately, I have been unable to recreate the issue in jsfiddle, so I'm not sure what is going on.

Some if the styles I use to influence the font-family and font-size can been seen at my attempt to recreate the issue at http://jsfiddle.net/K9hyG/2/.

When using the Chrome debugger, I can see the following in the Computed Style for one of the offending paragraphs:

```
border-collapse: separate;
color: rgb(51,51,51);
display: block;
font-family: Optima, Lucia, 'MgOpen Cosmetica', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
    font[size="2"] - 13px   default.aspx:427
    body - 13px             default.aspx:2
height: 36px;
text-align: left;
text-shadow: rgb(255,255,255) 0px 1px 0px;
width: 877px;
```

The text-shadow is generated by my usage of jQuery Mobile.  In the Chrome debugger, two instances of the text-shadow directive appear.  One inherited from div.ui-page.ui-body-c.ui-page-active (ui-body-c is the activating component) and the other from body.ui-mobile-viewport.ui-overlay-c, (ui-overlay-c is the activating component), but both definitions from the same section of CSS in the theme file.

If I deactivate one of them, the offending paragraph actually changes to 13px in Chrome Debugger, but still looks the same on the device.  If they are both deactivated in Chrome Debugger, then it goes back to 14px.  This still happens, even if the text-shadow set to `rgb(255,255,255) 0px 0px 0px`.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416989/computed-font-size-is-bigger-than-defined-in-css-on-the-asus-nexus-7), but that issue is largely unresolved as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A colleague of mine has discovered the answer.  It looks like I am the unwitting victim of [Font Boosting](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=FontBoosting)

As per the link, Font Boosting can be disabled by providing `max-height: 1000000px` on the element in question or on `body, body *` for all elements.

Comment: Thanks very much for this - it has resolved my most annoying problem of 2013 so far.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is likely due to Chrome's text scaling setting, which sets text at a particular scale for accessibility reasons. A lot of users use this who struggle to read small text on their mobile. You cannot fix this and shouldn't try to resolve it, especially with sites that support mobile devices.

[image: Chrome accessibility options]

I recommend you either ignore it or modify your CSS so that it supports slightly differing text sizes.

Comment: The Google Nexus 7 is marginally bigger than a mobile, and is classified as a tablet.  While I agree that the font size should be bigger, my client does not, and has specific requirements that the font size be consistent throughout the website.

Comment: Is there some Webkit specific CSS attribute which prevents this accessability scaling? This sizing breaks some parts of my layout and I'd like to disable scaling on those design elements.

Comment: @Danielku15 disabling scaling is a really bad idea, it's not possible as browsers have to be able to scale a page by law in many countries i believe. I guess take solace in the fact that a lot or sites break.

Comment: My plan is not to disable the scaling in general. As said: I have some design elements with fixed size. It's some text placed within an image. Because of the scaling the text overlaps the region where the image should take place. It's not a question if it's a bad idea, it's a question if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests this rule helped me out. Must be added either to the element containing boosted text or it's parent depending on the div/table structure.

```
element or parent element { 
    /* prevent font boosting on mobile devices */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 1px;
    max-height: 999999px;
}
```

Maybe the width and heigth values must be corrected according your needs.

Comment: As mentioned in [https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=FontBoosting], the max-height only needs to be greater than the current height to disable Font Boosting.  A large number is used to catch almost all cases.